# CSS border don't work on firefox

Tags: html, css, border

can someone tell me why this freaking code dont work on firefox but work on chrome and safari ? Any ideas ? i trying everything what i know, but i cant't i hope for you.

code

html

```
<div id="container_intro">  
  <span class="link1"><span class="bold">about</span>me</span>
  <span class="link2">my<span class="bold">works</span></span>
  <div class="logo_intro">
  <img class="rotation" src="images/symbol_bg.png">
  <img class="transparent" src="images/symbol_transparent.png"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
body {
margin:0px auto;
padding: 0px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
background:#FFF;
}

.link1 {
position: absolute;
top:42%;
left:20%;
display: block;
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
font-size:64px;
font-weight: 100;
color:#dc0000;
z-index: 50;
}

.link2 {
position: absolute;
top:42%;
right:20%;
display: block;
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
font-size:64px;
font-weight: 100;
color:#dc0000;
z-index: 50;
}

.demi {
font-weight: 400;
}
.bold {
font-weight: 700;
}

img {
width:100%;
}

#container_intro {
margin: 0px auto;
height:100vh;
min-height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

.logo_intro {
margin:0px auto;
overflow: hidden;
background: #fff;
opacity: 0.9;
width: 35%;
z-index: 50;
}

.black {
margin:0px auto;
padding:0px;
background: #000;
width:100%;
height:2400px;
}

/* ======================================================================== */
/* ! Animations
/* ======================================================================== */

.transparent {
z-index: 50;
border: 130px solid #ffffff;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left:-130px;
margin-top:-130px;

}
.rotation {
position: absolute;
width: 35%;
margin:0px auto;
margin-left:-10px;
margin-top:-10px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -1;
-webkit-animation-name: rotate;
-webkit-animation-duration:30s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
-moz-animation-name: rotate;
-moz-animation-duration:30s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-moz-animation-timing-function:linear;
animation-name: rotate;
animation-duration:30s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
animation-timing-function:linear;
background-position:center;
}
```

preview: www.nevisu.co.uk

Comment: You need to tell us what you want, and make a jsfiddle, because i cant find the CSS for a border in the coding you posted

Comment: What should it be doing in ff?

Comment: Weird. This is ghetto but fixes it: .logo_intro{outline: 200px solid #ffffff;} --- assuming the issue is the image overflow in firefox. That is the only visible difference between chrome and firefox for me.

Comment: Imagine WebDesign - sorry for no jsfiddle, the border is in animation .rotation.

Ted - yes this works, but i still see the '1px hole wide' do you ? update at www.nevisu.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

Interesting bug, overflow is acting silly.  Try this:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.logo_intro {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Should only change the value of overflow if in firefox.

Comment: hi :) ty for reply, yes this works (like the same what Ted suggested .logo_intro{outline: 200px solid #ffffff;} but in both way i still see 1px wide 'hole'? updated www.nevisu.co.uk

Comment: @nevisu what do you mean by a 1px wide 'hole'? Maybe try my solution below, maybe it'll get rid of this 1px wide 'hole', also it's less 'hacky' :)

Comment: @Nick B i try your way and the effect is that same... still have '1px hole' - http://i58.tinypic.com/awyx5t.png . but now i see sometimes when i scratch my browser window this hole dissapear sometimes show up the next one on the bottom i think this is all % fault

Comment: @nevisu Ok cool, well hopefully you get it all figured out. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` to `.logo-intro` and `width: 100%` to `.rotation`. See below:

```
.logo_intro {
    position: relative; /* Added */
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    width: 35%;
}

.rotation {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; /* Changed  */
    margin: -10px auto 0px -10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 30s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    background-position: center center;
}
```